# How to enable migration in SQLite using EF

Tags: c#, sqlite, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have stuck in problem. I am writing a code for windows desktop application and I have to use sqlite as a database. I have successfully installed `system.data.sqlite` and entity framework from nuget package. I have also created my DbContext class. Now problem is that as soon as I tried to run my code an exception comes whose inner message is

> {"SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: TimeSheet'"}.

This means your table TimeSheet does not exist in database. Plz tell me how to create table in sqlite using entity framework or how to enable migrations.

Comment: try https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some implementations of migration for SQLite.

https://github.com/bubibubi/db2ef6migrations is based on the new EF6 migration interface but it has some restrictions.
You can download it from Nuget searching for System.Data.SQLite.EF6.Migrations

Answer (score 7):

Unlike MS SQL Server, as default, the free Sqlite driver from [system.data.sqlite](https://system.data.sqlite.org) **doesn’t support Migration**.So you **can’t create** a new database from code.You **have to manually create** it.

For that you can use `SQLite Manager add-on for Firefox`.

Here is the link : [**SQLite Manager**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

Or you can use [**SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1) where **@ErikEJ** suggested below.

Comment: Or use the free SQLite Toolbox extension directly in Visual Studio

Comment: But brother I have to create database tables from my models. How can I do this?

Comment: Yes,above free driver doesn't support `migration`.So you have to create it `manually` by using one of the above tool.No other option.

Comment: Its possible by using MicrosoftEntityFramework Core that support sqlite. It works just like entityframework.