# EF Core Migration Potentially Destructive?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm setting up a .NET Core web service with EF Core integration and currently have migration configured for the DB schema (`context.Migrate()` is called in C# code). I'm wondering what would happen if EF Core detects an existing database for the given connection string that has vastly different schema such that it can't non-destructively migrate? Would EF Core nuke the existing DB and create the new schema or error out?

Comment: It should error out if it doesn't find the migrations already applied, but to be sure I'd copy one such different database and run the migration against it, just to be sure

Comment: Different schema would cause exception. The existed db will not be removed unless you remove it manually and then the EF would create a new db again

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the migration will work if  existed schema is related to models and needs some migration to update schema again to match the new changes in models

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247760/how-to-enable-migration-in-sqlite-using-ef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core would try and translate the migrations to SQL and the SQL would run. Because the schema's are different / not as expected, then the migrations would fail as an SQL Exception which would fall back up the chain to EF Core. (Essentially, the migration would fail and nothing would happen as everything is run under a transaction which is rolled back upon failure)